# php regex, making sure user doesnt add too many new line breaks

Tags: php, regex, line-breaks

Input form on my website for comments. I have some silly users creating a whole lot of blank whitespace by pressing enter [space] enter [space] or lots of enters etc
In PHP, how do I preserve legit single enter or double 'enter enter', but remove any other combinations with spaces inbetween.
eg, This is OK:

```
\n\n
```

This is NOT:

```
\n\n\n...
\n\n \n...
\n \n \n...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working and tested. I decided to break the process in two passes of replaces to keep the regex code simple (you can combine both if you desire).

First one (`/\n | {1,} | \n/`) will look for any random combination of spaces and `\n` characters, leaving the solo `\n`.

Second one (`'/(?<=\n{2})\n*/'`) makes use of look behind feature to match any group of `\n`characters that follows any '\n\n' (double new line sequence).

Testing:

```
$string ="
Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet\n
Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet\n
\n
Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet\n
\n
\n
Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet\n
\n
\n
\n
.\n
\n
..\n
.....\n
.\n
...\n
Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet";

$string = preg_replace('/\n | {1,} | \n/', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=\n{2})\n*/', '', $string);
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet\n
Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet\n
\n
Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet\n
\n
Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet\n
\n
Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
```

I'm not a regex guru, but I think it already solves the problem decently.

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_text = preg_replace('/\n\s+\n/','\n',$original_text)`
```

handles:

- more than two `\n` in a row (note `\s` is `[ \r\t\n]` so this pattern includes anything that matches `\n{3,}`)
- `\n` with whitespace in between followed by another `\n`. The `\s+` is greedy so will grab as many intermediate spaces and `\n` as it can.

Note that this regex replaces any part of the string that contains at least two `\n`s, except for `\n\n` (which you wanted to be preserved).

**EDIT** (thanks to @AlanMoore, see comments below): It replaces these "too many \n" occurences with a single `\n` rather than removes them entirely as your original question specified. This is because if the input string was `foo\n\n\nbar` it seems like you'd rather have `foo\nbar` than `foobar` as the result string.

If you do indeed want to remove all these occurences entirely, just replace with `''` above instead of `\n`.

Comment: Nice, but shouldn't the replacement string be `'\n\n'`?  Also, `\s` matches more characters than just `[ \r\t\n]` (but that doesn't make this regex any less valid).

Comment: Depends - OP said they wanted to preserve `\n` and `\n\n` but remove any other combinations, so I just replaced with ''.

Comment: If the original string is `foo\n\n\nbar`, you'll change it to `foobar`.  That doesn't look right to me.

Comment: I agree, I'll update my answer to replace with `\n` and explain why that might be desirable. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fixed = preg_replace('/\n\s+/', '\n', $bad);
```

Find any linebreak followed by 1 or more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, etc..) and replace it with a single linebreak.

Comment: This doesn't account for valid entries of \n\n nor does it account for "\n\n \n \n \n\n" etc (all blank space). If possible, can all blank space be condensed into a maximum output of double enter \n\n ?

Comment: I'd use str_replace() instead of preg_replace() since there's no need for the use of regex.

Comment: @Soliver: that presumes these evil people are consistently evil and don't do multiple spaces in varying quantities. str_replace is good for unvarying fixed single patterns.